# Is there a way to repeatedly pass a changing array to Java Canvas and have it update the screen?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create a program to visualize bubble sort. Ideally, after bubble sort swaps two numbers in an array, AWT would redraw rectangles on the canvas to show the array updating.

I originally tried having the sorting and drawing portions in different classes, but this caused issues with passing the array between classes and conversions between static and non-static methods.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VisMain extends Canvas {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int[] array;

    public static void bubble_srt(int array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                    swapNumbers(i, k, array);
                }   

            }
        }
    }

    private static void swapNumbers(int i, int j, int[] column) {

        int temp;
        temp = column[i];
        column[i] = column[j];
        column[j] = temp;
        VisMain set = new VisMain();
       set.arraySetter(column);
    }

    public void arraySetter(int[] list) {
        this.array = list;
                repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
            Canvas canvas = new VisMain();
            canvas.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.add(canvas);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            int [] input = { 4, 2, 5, 6, 33, 15, 34, 0, 1, 99 };
            VisMain obj = new VisMain();
            obj.arraySetter(input);
            bubble_srt(input);
        }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
                g.drawRect((i + 1) * 60, 100 , 50, array[i]);
            }

    }
    }
```

I expected the canvas to at least display something but I got a `java.lang.NullpointerException` in the `for() loop` in the `paint()` method.

Comment: `<= array.length` You'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I have edited that to be `< array.length`, thank you. But I am still getting a null pointer exception by calling array.length even though it is a private variable in the same class.

Comment: Try marking your array as `volatile`

Comment: The paint method is being called automatically when the frame is made visible.  At that point, your array is still null.  You need to assign your array `this.array = input` before anything else.  Try making that the first thing in your main method.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment.  This should fix the problem: Insert `((VisMain)canvas).array = input;` just after `Canvas canvas = new VisMain();`.

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) `Canvas canvas = new VisMain();
            canvas.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.add(canvas);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            int [] input = { 4, 2, 5, 6, 33, 15, 34, 0, 1, 99 };
            VisMain obj = new VisMain() ..` How does it make sense to declare the canvas **twice**?

Answer (score 1):

This line of your code...

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

causes your `paint(Graphics g)` method to be invoked which causes the `NullPointerException` since, at this stage, member `array` of class `VisMain` is still null (according to the code you posted).

Hence you need to assign a value to `array` **before** calling `frame.setVisible(true)`.

The below code works for me, i.e. no `NullPointerException` using JDK 12.0.1 on Windows 10. It is basically the code you posted. The only part I changed was in method `main()` but for completeness I post all of the code you posted including my changes so you can copy/paste it.

```
package guitests;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VisMain extends Canvas {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int[] array;

    public static void bubble_srt(int array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                    swapNumbers(i, k, array);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void swapNumbers(int i, int j, int[] column) {
        int temp;
        temp = column[i];
        column[i] = column[j];
        column[j] = temp;
        VisMain set = new VisMain();
        set.arraySetter(column);
    }

    public void arraySetter(int[] list) {
        this.array = list;
        repaint();
    }

    /* Only this method is changed from original code posted by DeusDeus. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        int[] input = {4, 2, 5, 6, 33, 15, 34, 0, 1, 99};
        VisMain obj = new VisMain();
        obj.arraySetter(input);
        obj.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(obj);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        bubble_srt(input);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            g.drawRect((i + 1) * 60, 100, 50, array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I appreciate your help and input, otherwise I would have been stuck for days.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.NullpointerException` as your `array` is `null`. Please fix that and your code should work. You cannot get `array.length` of null.

I am editing my answer  as I like the answer presented by @Abra

Comment: I understand my array is null but I cannot understand why my array is null. It is initialized as a private variable of the same class and setting the value of the array is the first 3 lines of code in main(). I created a test public static void method that can access array but the paint() method can not.